# Can Chromecast cast .m3u8 live stream on default receiver?

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I have tried casting .mp4 on default receiver. It works great. Used the same setting to play m3u8 and metadata comes but video doesn't play.
Want to know if I can cast .m3u8 as well on the default receiver. If so what MIME type should I use and additional setting should I set?

Comment: Asking the content provider to add CORS headers to the m3u8 file stream. once cors was added everything worked fine. Also read my comment on Ali naddaf's answer to know abt mime type..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HLS (if that is what is in your m3u8 playlist) is supported. You need to make sure CORS requirements are satisfied (something that is not required for plain mp4). Look at the docs under https://developers.google.com/cast/ to see what is supported and what is not, and find references to sample projects there as well.

Comment: Answering the mime type I asked - Usually for HLS it is  application/x-mpegurl or application/vnd.apple.mpegurl(Can be found out by inspecting headers, I used Postman REST client chrome app). Also, using http://test-cors.org one can test if CORS is supported by the URL.

Answer (score -10):

The .m3u8 format cannot be directly sent to Chromecast. But I'm using the APP: TVS_player

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.ielettronica.TVS_player

you need to have an account here: https://www.iptv-updated.com and add the .m3u8 in the channels groups. (more detail in this link: https://www.iptv-updated.com/how-to-stream-m3u8-on-chromecast/)