# Unable to stream video on chrome cast device

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, m3u8

Hi I am developing small android application in which I am enabling chrome cast support. I have built small video streaming application and tried to stream it on chrome cast device. If use media file with mp4 extension then it is working fine but when I tried to stream media file with m3u8 extension then it is not working. My media info data looks like this

```
      mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder("http://example.com/videos/hercules.mp4/playlist.m3u8")
     .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
     .setContentType("video/m3u8")
     .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
     .build();
```

I tried with `setContentType("video/application/x-mpegURL")` and also `setContentType("video/vnd.apple.mpegURL")` but it is not able to stream data. But on device it is working fine but on chrome cast device it is not working properly.

Is there any solution for this. Need help. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to use this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178164/can-chromecast-cast-m3u8-live-stream-on-default-receiver

Comment: You need to provide console log to see what is happening; make sure CORS requirements are satisfied.

Comment: Where I have to mention CORS requirements on receiver side or sender side? My sender side is android media streaming application and receiver side is chromecast html5 default application.

Answer (score 2):

The correct mimetype for m3u8 files that you set for the content type should be `application/x-mpegURL`. And for the stream type, m3u8 videos should be `MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED` while HLS streams should be `MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE`

```
mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder("http://example.com/videos/hercules.mp4/playlist.m3u8")
 .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
 .setContentType("application/x-mpegURL")
 .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
 .build();
```